# Set last grid to full width using GridLayoutManager (RecyclerView)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I am using a `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` to show some items in grid pattern. It's working good and showing items in 2 columns inside grid.

But when the number of items is odd, I want that the last item has to be full width (same as width of `RecyclerView`).

Is there anyway to do it using `GridLayoutManager` or I have to build custom design?

Please help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use `layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup` method from `GridLayoutManager`

Here is the way to use that

```
final GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 2);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                if (mAdapter != null) {
                    switch (mAdapter.getItemViewType(position)) {
                        case 1:
                            return 1;
                        case 0:
                            return 2; //number of columns of the grid
                        default:
                            return -1;
                    }
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        });
```

Now you have to determine the `viewType` in your `adapter`

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return (position == getItemCount() - 1) ? 0 : 1; // If the item is last, `itemViewType` will be 0
}
```

Keep building better apps!!

Comment: Saved me days and days searching. Thanks

Comment: Can anyone please help. I'm trying this but I'm getting only one column on screen. But when I remove the method setSpanSizeLookup, I'm getting total 2 columns.
I'm trying to achieve the same as mentioned in the question. I have 7 items in grid and the last grid item should be fill width.
Thanks in advance.